# Error is occured while installing Google.Apis.Youtube.v3 using Nuget package manager

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, google-api, nuget-package, youtube-data-api

I want to display youtube videos which are uploaded in my channel using YouTube api key of my project.(website)

For that I need to integrate the `Google.Apis.Youtube.v3` using c#.

I referred this [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/145c93/get-all-the-video-of-a-youtube-channel-using-jquery/).

But while installing package I got this error:

> 'Google.Apis.YouTube.v3' already has a dependency defined for
>   'NETStandard.Library'

**My visual studio configuration is as follows:**

- Visual studio version = **2012**
- Target framework = **4.0**
- Nuget version = **2.8.60**

Anybody have idea about it ?

Answer (score 0):

This error can often be fixed by installing the latest nuget package manager for your version of visual studio.   Remember to reboot visual studio after.